# How to skew / shear text in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, cs6, skew

So, in doing a commissioned logo for a church, I learned the hard way that, apparently, font-skewing (as opposed to warping) has been removed in Illustrator CS6. I'm not sure why and now that I'm looking for a clean alternative, so far, to no avail.

I want to create my own skewed font-face, I'm wondering what other Illustrator artists, who use CS6 and CC, are doing to sharpen their skew technique, if at all.

**How can I make text lean to the left or right, ie. skew or shear it, in Adobe Illustrator CS6 or CC?**

Answer (score 10):

From the menu, choose `Object > Transform > Shear` or <kbd>Right Mouse Button[image]</kbd>/<kbd>Control</kbd>-Click (Mac) and choose *Transform > Shear*. That Should do the trick.

[image]

You could also go to the **Transform Panel** in the top right of your screen (Or `Window > Transform`), like you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @GiantCowFilms I would like to contribute to a third way to do it:

I also use <kbd>E</kbd> to bring the Transform tool, click and drag the upper (or lower) middle manipulator and while dragging I hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to start the Shear. I also use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to avoid distortions.